# How to dynamiclly call SOLID princles following classes

Tags: python, solid-principles

I have a module where I try to follow the SOLID principles to create and generate data and I think the following is based around the Liskov Substitution Principle:

```py
class BaseLoader(ABC):

    def __init__(self, dataset_name='mnist'):
        self.dataset_name=dataset_name


class MNISTLoader(BaseLoader):

    def load(self):
        # Logic for loading the data
        pass


class OCTMNISTLoader(Baseloader):
 
    def download(self):
        # Logic for downloading the data
        pass
```

Now I want to create an instance based on a parsed argument or a loaded config file, I wonder if the following is the best practice or if better ways exist to create dynamically   an instance:

```py
possible_instances = {'mnist': MNISTLoader, 'octmnist': OCTMNISTLoader}

choosen_dataset = 'mnist'

instance = possible_instances[choosen_dataset](dataset_name=choosen_dataset)
```

##### EDIT #1:

We also thought about using a function to call the classes dynamically. This function is than placed inside the module, which includes the classes:

```py
def get_loader(loader_name:str) -> BaseLoader:
    loaders = {
        'mnist': MNISTLoader,
        'octmnist': OCTMNISTLoader    
    }
    try:
        return loaders[loader_name]
    except KeyError as err:
        raise CustomError("good error message")
```

I am still not shure which is the most pythonic way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this has much to do with LSP since both classes inherit only from an abstract base class that never gets instantiated. You are simply sharing a dataset_name member of the base class to reduce code duplication. And forget about the default value in argument `dataset_name='mnist'` it has no point the way you are using it.

I don't know much about Python, but to instantiate a class from a string you would usually want to have a factory class where you would use whatever ugly method you come up with to map a string to an instance of a matching class, perhaps a simple if/elif. The factory method could contain something like this.

```
if loader_name == "mnist":
  return MNISTLoader(loader_name)
elif loader_name == "octmnist":
  return OCTMNISTLoader(loader_name)
# but you probably don't need to pass loader_name argument
```

While the above is not an elegant solution, you now have a reusable class with a method that is the single source of truth for how strings should map to type.

Also, you may remove the dataset_name init argument and member, unless you have a reason for objects to hold that information. I guess you tried to use the base init method like a factory but that's not the way to go.

One problem your code has is the methods "load" and "download", how will you know which one of the two methods to call if you fetch instances dynamically? Again, if you named them differently because you thought this had something to do with LSP, it doesn't. You are losing the advantage of polymorphism by having two methods with different names. Just have both classes extend the same abstract method (since you're using the ABC thing) "load" and be done with it. Then you can do `whatever_the_object_type_is.load()`

Comment: You are right about most things, which we came up ourself in the meantime, especially the polymorphism issue. At the moment we stick to dictionary calling, because it is basically the same as putting everything into a factory class with if else statements. Since this is a question about the most pythonic way to use this I leave the question open for know.

Comment: @MaKaNu good, I hope the dictionary is still inside a factory class. I think what you are doing is pretty python way already. If your goal is clean code you will want to stick with what is most readable, using some potentially more advanced trick would hide real intent.